# Automating bugzilla metrics query

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have been using bugzillametrics to generate metrics from Bugzilla. I really love the product. One of the things that I am trying to do is to automate the query process, meaning, instead of opening up a browser and running the query link everyday, i want to run it using a cronjob. In talking with the developer of bugzillametrics, looks like there is a client side javascript that runs to generate the snapshot from the query. To automate the process, I am using phantomjs. However, with my phantomjs script, the client side javascript does not run and I dont get any graph. here is what i am trying to do

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var postBody1 = '';

page.open('http://1.1.1.1:8080/BugzillaMetrics1_3/#calculate_query,6.0.5a/',function(status) {
console.log('Status: ' + status);
var content = page.content;
console.log('Content: ' + content);
});
```

When I run it using the command line "./phantomjs post.js", I get the o/p

```
Status: success
Content: <!DOCTYPE html><html class=" ext-strict"><head>
<It also downloads the html source and displays it here".
```

However, the query does not run because I dont see any snapshot being created in the database of bugzillametrics.

If I go to the query using the browser, I see the following in the access_log

```
1.1.1.1 - - [02/Sep/2014:14:47:29 -0700] "POST /BugzillaMetrics1_3/MetricsUI/MetricResultService HTTP/1.1" 200 165
1.1.1.1 - - [02/Sep/2014:14:47:30 -0700] "POST /BugzillaMetrics1_3/MetricsUI/MetricResultService HTTP/1.1" 200 147
1.1.1.1 - - [02/Sep/2014:14:47:30 -0700] "GET /BugzillaMetrics1_3/ajax-loader.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 6494
1.1.1.1 - - [02/Sep/2014:14:47:30 -0700] "GET /BugzillaMetrics1_3/MetricsUI/displayResult?filename=Total_Bugs_in_this_release_02-09-2014_14-47-29_909.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 158214
```

Looks like my phantomjs script is not correct ? What can I do to fix this ?

Thanks,
Sunray

Comment: Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Maybe you simply need to use `setTimeout` to let the page do its thing before you check the content. You should also use `phantom.exit();` to terminate phantom when the script is done (inside of the callbacks).

Comment: Finally got back to this issue again. If I open the phantomjs remote debugger and execute my phantomjs script using "__run()", the bugzilla query works fine. The same script from shell using "./phantomjs post1.js" does not work. Why is that ? I dont seem to find examples with setTimeout.

Comment: Did the [event handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067919/automating-bugzilla-metrics-query?noredirect=1#comment40843518_26067919) show anyting suspicious?

Comment: Where can I add the event handlers ? I added the onError like this and I see no related output when I execute the script. Not sure if I adding the eventhandlers correctly

Comment: You add the event handlers before the task that you want observed. Also, please add all of them.